# Function such that: $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \langle x, \nabla f(x)\rangle$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to show that if $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(0) = 0, \nabla f(0) = 0$ and $$f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \langle x, \nabla f(x)\rangle $$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then $f$ must be of the form $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \langle x, Ax \rangle$ for some matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. We may not assume that $f$ is anything more than continuously differentiable.

This seems like a really easy problem, but I am stumped. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: To be sure: you are writing $\langle x,Ax \rangle$ to mean the usual dot product in $\mathbb{R}^n$, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: $f$ is a divergence: $$\begin{aligned}\frac12x\cdot\nabla f(x) &= \frac12\nabla\cdot(xf(x)) - \frac12f(x)\nabla\cdot x \\ &= \frac12\nabla\cdot(xf(x)) - \frac n2f(x),\end{aligned}$$ hence $$f(x) = \frac12\nabla\cdot(xf(x)) - \frac n2f(x) $$$$ \implies f(x) = \nabla\cdot\left(\frac{xf(x)}{2+n}\right).$$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Euler's_theorem